# The wrong characters are getting stripped when using Sed

Tags: sed

I'm using (or attempting to use) a sed instruction to strip leading and trailing whitespaces and/or empty lines from lines of text ...

`sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//;/^$/d'`

It's working, but its also seems to be stripping backslashes from my text.

For example, with an input string: `test\\\test` the result is: `test\test`

I'm assuming this is avoidable but I'm struggling with it.  Any help would be much appreciated.
For reference, I'm calling this as a shell script from within AppleScriptObjC

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not sed. Are you forgetting to quote your variables?

```
$ str='test\\\test'
$ echo "$str"
test\\\test
$ sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//;/^$/d' <<< "$str"
test\\\test
```

Btw, I'd use `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[ \t]`

Comment: Thanks of the quick reply Glenn ... the full command I'm trying with is `do shell script "echo " & |quote| & theText & |quote| & "|sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//;/^$/d'"`

Comment: I've revised the script according to your suggestion Glenn and it seems to have improved the situation but not cured it? ... instead of stripping away two backslash chars in now strips only one ... the new code line is `set thetext to do shell script "sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//;/^$/d' <<< " & |quote| & theText & |quote|`

Comment: I believe you're missing Mr Jackman's point: it isn't sed that's stripping the backslashes, it's the shell pipe you are using to feed sed.  Or awk.

Comment: Thanks for the hint mpez0. Yep, I totally got Glenn's point ... what I didn't get is a better understanding of how to quote the contents of the darn thing so that it works :/ No worries, I'll keep at it! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks again Glenn ... I've change the syntax of the call using Applescript builtin-in quoting support rather than manually quoting it myself ... and finally it works. Thank you again for the tips. `set theText to do shell script "sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//;/^$/d' <<< " & the quoted form of (theText as text)`

Comment: After all this time, this is the first you've said "applescript". That would have been an important detail to lead with, hmm?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this simpler and more robust:

```
awk 'NF { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,""); print }'
```

Comment: Hmmm. Sadly exactly the same result as with my earlier sed attempts ... if I pass it `test\\\test` it returns with `test\test' ... the code I tried with is `set theText to do shell script "echo " & |quote| & theText & |quote| & " |awk 'NF { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/," & |quote| & |quote| &"); print }'"`